# Android saving image using native camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to launch the native android camera and save the image at a specified location. The problem is after I click the photo, the preview comes up with the options to Save/Discard. After I click save the camera launches again, and the image I captured is not saved in the specified location. Rather it gets saved in the default location. Actually I need the location of the image I clicked. Here's the code I use to launch the camera.

```
MediaScannerConnection_MSC = null;
String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
_imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
// create new Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Here's the code after returning from the camera

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // use imageUri here to access the image

                final String imagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                _MSC = new MediaScannerConnection(this, new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {

                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        _MSC.scanFile(imagePath, null);
                    }

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        _MSC.disconnect();
                        _MSC = null;
                    }

                });
                _MSC.connect();

            }
        }
    }
```

what mistake am I doing here

Comment: I have a very similar question.  Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have your answer, I've searched high and low for this one, and it's kinda tricky.

First of all, I think on certain phones,

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _imageUri);
```

is ignored :-(

So my best answer for you is, don't set the "EXTRA_OUTPUT" flag, instead, let it run normally and return your new picture URI.  Then, from there, use:

```
Uri u = intent.getData();
```

To get your new picture's info, then from there, I use a FileOutputStream to write the image file to the new location I want to have it to.  Then, lastly, I delete the original file. :-)

I know it's kind of hokey, but it works, and I think it's pretty dependable. :-)

I hope that helps. :-)

-Jared

8-28-11

@llango J

Ok, well, here's the entire code, you're welcome to copy and paste it and see if you can get that to work :-)

For starters, you will want to call the camera like this:

```
startActivityForResult(CameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Then, for the result you will want this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            Uri u = intent.getData();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), u.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            WriteFiles(u);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

And then the main magic happens in this function:

```
private void WriteFiles(Uri myNewPic) {
    String TempFilePath;
    String TempPath;

    File directory = new File("/sdcard/" + getString(R.string.app_name));

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    String TempPictureFile;
    try {
        TempPictureFile = myNewPic.getLastPathSegment() + ".jpg";
        TempFilePath = directory.getPath() + "/" + TempPictureFile;
        FileOutputStream myOutStream = new FileOutputStream(TempFilePath);
        InputStream myInStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myNewPic);
        FileIO myFileIO = new FileIO();
        myFileIO.copy(myInStream, myOutStream);
        //now delete the file after copying
        getContentResolver().delete(myNewPic, null, null);
        TempFilePaths.add(TempFilePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.ErrorOpeningFileOutput), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I think that is all the parts you need in order to save using the native camera app.  However, I must caution you, I eventually wound up abandoning this code because I needed more flexibility and dependability than this offered (I'm thinking if you use this app on a ton of different phones, I could see it having problems for one reason or another.  Like for example, I've had a TON of problems as a result of Samsung customizing their UI, therefore things work great on all phones but the Samsung ones. :-P).  So I wound up just creating a camera app of my own, but I'm sure depending on your application this might work just fine for you.  Either way.... good luck! :-)

Ok, here's my FileIO class that I use, sorry I didn't include this initially:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.util.Log;

public class FileIO {
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 2;

public FileIO() {
    // Utility class.
}

public int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Exception, IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input, BUFFER_SIZE);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(output, BUFFER_SIZE);
    int count = 0, n = 0;
    try {
        while ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), null);
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), null);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

}
```

Comment: Ok let me give it a try and see how it comes up

Comment: @llango J , I have revised and expanded the code so you can just copy and paste it into your app.  Please let me know if that does not fix it for you. :-)

Comment: @Jared this didn't work for me, for a start you're trying to call `add()` on `String` which doesn't exist, also, what are those IO classes you're using?

Comment: @James.Elsey I just revised the code to get rid of that string that didn't exist.  It was only there because I had to do some heavy trimming on my original code to make it easier for you guys.  Speaking of which, I've included my FileIO class I was using so you can just use that as well.  I hope that helps! :-)